# Why does VirtualGL raise a *Could not open display :0* error after host reboot

Tags: vnc, reboot, opengl

I am using vncserver to connect to a CentOS7 machine in the network. In order to make use of 3D graphics accelerations I am using [VirtualGL](https://virtualgl.org/). So any OpenGL program needs to be launched with *vglrun*  to make use of OpenGL.

This works like a charm but only if I log myself in on DISPLAY 0 and launch at least one OpenGL application beforehand. In other words:

If I

- reboot the machine,
- directly start a vncserver and
- connect to it with a client,

no OpenGL application is working and I get the error

```
[VGL] ERROR: Could not open display :0.
```

As soon as I log myself in on DISPLAY 0 and start an OpenGL application the error does not occur anymore until the machine is rebooted again.

My question:
How can I run OpenGL applications with *vglrun* without first running an OpenGL application on DISPLAY 0 after rebooting the machine?

Answer (score 0):

As posted in this question: [Setting up vnc server and no physical display : Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/326234/setting-up-vnc-server-and-no-physical-display-ubuntu-16-04-lts)

The solution to the problem is to have the following lines in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`:

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    Option         "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "True" # <-- This line is new
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I reinstalled VirtualGL and this time I added the `gdm` user to the `vglusers` group:

`sudo adduser gdm vglusers`